# Git Bash and Composer - Running without an extension

Tags: git, composer-php, msysgit

I've installed Git for Windows, configured to use Git commands exclusively in Git Bash.

So I have a file `composer.cmd` sitting beside `composer.phar` which looks like this:

```
@echo off
php C:\bin\composer.phar %*
```

However, I still need to enter `.cmd` or `.phar` at the end of the command for it to see it. The extension `.CMD` exists in `$PATHEXT` but it doesn't seem to matter. Having to retype a command because I left off the extension breaks my rhythm, and it seems incredibly arbitrary that I'm able to run `.exe` files without the extensions.

I want to know if there's a way to coerce it into accepting that `.cmd` files do not need to have their extensions specified. And I'm not using the MSI package to install Composer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a new file in the same dir as composer.bat and just call it `composer` without extension. Include this line:

```
cmd "/C composer.bat $@"
```

After this the command should work from git bash:

```
composer -V
```

Answer (score 0):

Since a [CMD session supports both `.bat` and `.cmd`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/148968/6309), check if your same script could be called without extension while being named `composer.bat`

I know I can call my scripts (`.bat`) without `.xxx`

Bit from a git bash session, I need to add cmd /C:

```
git bash
cmd "/C myscript"
# or
cmd //c myscript
```

See:

- "[how do I execute a batch file and then return to git console?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11878147/6309)")
- "[Weirdness when running a command with `CMD.exe /C` with args](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21907301/6309)"

`myscript` can be a `myscript.bat`, as long as it is in the Windows PATH, it will be executed.
And right after its execution, you are back in the git bash.

Or you could wrap the .bat/.cmd script in a shell script:

```
$ cat myscript.sh
cmd << EOD
myscript $@
EOD
$
```

In that case, a simple `myscript` would be enough.

Comment: I tried that, Git Bash still requires the extension.

Comment: @DissidentRage OK. I have edited the answer to propose some workaround.