# OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"-it\": executable file not found in $PATH":unknown

Tags: docker

I am not able to run the container from the image in docker for windows version 18.03.1-ce. I am trying to run the command:

```
  docker run ubuntu -it /bin/bash
```

Somehow it is not able to find the path of the `/bin/bash`. I don't know why this is happening.

Comment: Wrong order of arguments, try ```docker run -it ubuntu /bin/bash```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The docker command line is order sensitive. The order of args goes:

```
docker ${args_to_docker} run ${args_to_run} image_ref ${cmd_in_container}
```

Everything after `ubuntu` in your command goes to the command trying to be run. In your case `-it`. What you want instead is to pass `-it` to "run" so that you get interactive input with a tty terminal associated.

```
docker run -it ubuntu /bin/bash
```

Answer (score -1):

This error encountered when trying to run command that is not in docker container `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin`. If you have let's say **rar** installed in the docker then you can run rar command via docker exec, if you don't, will get the error above.

Also don't use -t only use -i like below:

```
docker exec -i <container_name> <command>
docker exec -i <container_name> rar
```

Answer (score -2):

Before trying anything, check your docker version, update, and try again.