# Can't run docker image

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, dockerfile, alpine-linux

First, sorry if my question sounds too easy or silly. I'm new to docker. 
I have created my docker image and passed several jar files which are to be run immediately when the container starts. 
I want to run the script "serve.sh" immediately when the container starts
I succeeded in creating the images well, but when I run the container, it throws me this error:

> C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"-it\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.

Here is the command I use to run the image I craeted:

```
docker run b24b37614e1a -it
```

Here is my docker file:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
EXPOSE 8080:8080
COPY apigateway-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar apigateway.jar
COPY authservice-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar authservice.jar
COPY institutionsservice-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar institutionsservice.jar
COPY messagesservice-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar messagesservice.jar
COPY postsservice-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar postsservice.jar
COPY userservice-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar userservice.jar
COPY serve.sh serve.sh
CMD [ "bash" "./serve.sh" ]
```

Please what am I doing wrong ? I'm new to docker

Comment: Does it work with `CMD [ "/bin/bash" "./serve.sh" ]`? Or else, I'm not sure, but chances are that alpine images don't contain bash. They're designed to be tiny.

Comment: Eh, didn't notice your argument order either. It should be [`docker run -it b24b37614e1a`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62053877/507738) indeed.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50761557/596285

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of things which you should correct, First one is the `CMD` format which should be

```
CMD instruction has three forms:

CMD ["executable","param1","param2"] (exec form, this is the preferred form)
CMD ["param1","param2"] (as default parameters to ENTRYPOINT)
CMD command param1 param2 (shell form)
```

```
CMD [ "/bin/bash" , "./serve.sh" ]
```

Another thing, When you do `docker run`, the instructions are

```
Usage:  docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE [COMMAND] [ARG...]
```

which means all the options has to be before `IMAGE` and in your case `it` is appearing after `IMAGE`.

The correct command should be

```
docker run -it b24b37614e1a
```

*BTW*, small question, why you want to run an interactive container of this application. Ideally, it should be something like

```
docker run -p $HOST_PORT:$APP_PORT b24b37614e1a
```

`-p` => Publish a container's port(s) to the host

and then you can access your application `localhost:$HOST_PORT` or `machine_IP:$HOST_PORT`

Comment: Thanks, please does the EXPOSE instruction replace the -p ? I though it did, I added it to my docker file hopping it will do just that

Comment: Thanks, I did exactly what you said, but now, I get this error: "sh: ./serve.sh: unknown operand"  I updated My CMD instruction to: CMD [ "bin/bash" "./serve.sh" ]

Comment: Edited my answer and added CMD, please have a look

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind that docker args order matters:
you wrote `docker run b24b37614e1a -it` which is different from

```js
docker run -it b24b37614e1a
```

Hope it solves your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

- `docker run -it` *then* args (c/o Luca Fabbian)
- You don't have `bash`. Use `sh`. (c/o MC Emperor)
- **CMD exec form needs an array, so use commas**: `CMD ["sh", "./serve.sh"]`
- CMD has a shell form if you forget syntax easily: `CMD ./serve.sh`
- Don't even exec the shell if you don't have to: `CMD ["./serve.sh"]`

### Argument order matters

This assumes you already took Luca's [advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62053877/13025424):

> Keep in mind that docker args order matters:
> you wrote docker run b24b37614e1a -it which is different from docker run -it b24b37614e1a

### You don't have `bash`.

I pulled the `openjdk:8-jdk-alpine` image to confirm, and it does not come with bash. Alpine images come with `sh` so the code provided will *never* work unless you correct the shell used or install bash.

### "unknown operand"

From your response to nischay:

> I get this error: "sh: ./serve.sh: unknown operand"

> I updated My CMD instruction to: CMD [ "bin/bash" "./serve.sh" ]

CMD in the exec form takes an array of instructions. **These must be separated by a comma.**

Do this:

```
CMD [ "executable", "param1" ]
                  ^
```

### A note on using CMD

As nischay [said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62054186/13025424), there are a few different ways to use CMD to do roughly the same thing, [from the reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) quoted.

You *can* in fact use the exec form of CMD to say things like:

```
CMD [ "sh", "./serve.sh" ]
```

Typing out `/bin/sh` or `/bin/bash` or whichever shell you want is not required unless desired. But if you don't need the shell, you can use exec form without the shell as well:

```
CMD [ "./serve.sh" ]
```