# Docker Healcheck with net core

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

I encountered a problem. The problem is the `docker ps` command displays my container's healthy status always as **unhealthy**

I've reproducted that issue and pushed to Github: https://github.com/korenb/docker-healthcheck-aspnetcore.git

My steps:

- I configured the healthcheck endpoint in aspnetcore project. The path is `/health`
- Then I created docker stuff and set **HEALTHCHECK** property as desribed in [official docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#healthcheck)
- When I run the container I see its status as **unhealthy** permanently

The check command is `curl --fail http://localhost/health || exit 1`

I'm surprised that if I run that command through `docker exec <container> curl --fail http://localhost/health` then it works

I get some logs from `docker inspect <container>` but I really have no idea what's wrong.

```
{
    "Status": "unhealthy",
    "FailingStreak": 22,
    "Log": [{
            "Start": "2019-03-12T13:27:51.570474Z",
            "End": "2019-03-12T13:27:51.6708017Z",
            "ExitCode": -1,
            "Output": "OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:344: starting container process caused \"exec: \\\"curl --fail http://localhost/health || exit 1\\\": stat curl --fail http://localhost/health || exit 1: no such file or directory\": unknown"
        },
        {
            "Start": "2019-03-12T13:27:53.8550082Z",
            "End": "2019-03-12T13:27:53.9882208Z",
            "ExitCode": -1,
            "Output": "OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:344: starting container process caused \"exec: \\\"curl --fail http://localhost/health || exit 1\\\": stat curl --fail http://localhost/health || exit 1: no such file or directory\": unknown"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm desperate so I hope the community will help me to figure out the problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: (...) executable file not found in $PATH": unknown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48001082/oci-runtime-exec-failed-exec-failed-executable-file-not-found-in-path)

Answer (score -1):

> the devil is in the details

I found out from [OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: (…) executable file not found in $PATH": unknown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48001082/oci-runtime-exec-failed-exec-failed-executable-file-not-found-in-path) that the command must be clean of any quotes around.

So in dockerfile I replaced this

```
HEALTHCHECK ... CMD ["curl --fail http://localhost/health || exit 1"]
```

by this

```
HEALTHCHECK ... CMD curl --fail http://localhost/health || exit 1
```

You can see it here https://github.com/korenb/docker-healthcheck-aspnetcore/commit/6a24b394b9d60bab75d2b7daf549aa86576c2bb5