# File path as parameter - I/O Error: Couldn't open file

Tags: bash, batch-file

I'm trying to open a batch file using Git Bash with a file path as parameter. I can grab the parameter using `%1`. However, when I give it the path, I get this error:

> I/O Error: Couldn't open file 'C:UsersUsernameDownloadsFile.pdf'

I run my batch like this:

```
count.bat C:\Users\Username\Downloads\File.pdf
```

I've tried replacing `\` with `/` in the file path, which works, but I'm going to drag'n'drop a file into command prompt, and I don't want to replace all the backslashes. Here's what I've done:

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set variable="%1"
call set variable=%%variable:\=/%%

pdftotext %variable% -enc UTF-8 - | wc -m
```

That should replace `\` with `/` but it doesn't. I get the same output doing this versus simply doing `pdftotext %1 -enc....`.

EDIT: Turns out Git Bash treats `\` as an escape character. This means I can't simply type in the path without quotes around it, as it would try to escape it. I ended up using geisterfurz007's suggestion about opening cmd.exe, then do the `file.bat`, which would call `sh.exe` on my `file.sh` file, which would THEN do the whole operation. A workaround but at least now it works using cmd.

Comment: No need for delayed expansion, and no need for `call` and double-`%` here... Sometimes (depending on the program) replacing a single backslash by double-backslashes might also help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what exactly the problem is for you but the following does the job for me:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set variable="%~1"
set variable=%variable:\=/%
echo %variable%
```

Notice the `~` in `%~1` This will automatically remove surrounding quotes if there are any. I am not sure if the call or the double `%` were causing the problem but they are not needed in this case if I am not mistaken.

Usage: `foo.bat "C:\my Path\to\yeeeeey.file"`

Output: `"C:/my Path/to/yeeeeey.file"`

Usage: `foo.bat C:\Users\Username\Downloads\File.pdf`

Output: `"C:/Users/Username/Downloads/File.pdf"`

EDIT: After a longer chat session with MortenMoulder we found a workaround for this: It seems that starting Git-Bash with a bash file including his one command `pdftotext $1 -enc UTF-8 - | wc -m` with the parameter from the batch file seemed to work:

batch-file.bat:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set variable="%~1"
set variable=%variable:\=/%
C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe C:\Users\Username\count.sh %variable%
```

count.sh:

```
pdftotext $1 -enc UTF-8 - | wc -m
```

Comment: That's because you're surrounding your path with double quotes. That's not always the case. Look at my example. The path has no spaces, which means double quotes aren't necessary.

Comment: Nope! See my edit. It does not matter if you are surrounding it with quotes when starting the file. Have a look at the first line under my code please. If there are no quotes, none will removed (obviously) but if there are any they will be removed.

Comment: I'm not getting the same results as you. Hmm. When I do `echo %variable%` it gives me `C:UsersUsernameDownloadsFile.pdf`.

Comment: Then it seems like you have `set variable=%variable:\=%` (missing `/` after the `=` )... Have you just copied the code I got?

Comment: Yes I have copied exactly what you have.

Comment: Hmm I noticed this only appears to be a problem using Git Bash. Basically bash. It works fine using command prompt. I thought it would execute the same regardless? :O

Comment: Ayyy Bash aint Batch! Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22397521/execute-commands-from-bat-file-on-git-bash-terminal) where someone seemed to have the same problem.

Comment: I'm writing this this in batch though. Everything is batch except I need to run it in Git Bash (or any other bash terminal) because of `pdftotext` and `wc`. Also, I can run it fine. No problem with that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129019/discussion-between-geisterfurz007-and-mortenmoulder).