# MSysGit - run bat files directly

Tags: windows, cmd, msysgit

I installed new version of MSysGit and now I am not able to run *.bat files directly from command line("called MINGW64").

I try to search it, but I only saw options which needs run cmd first.
[Out of a git console: how do I execute a batch file and then return to git console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11865085/out-of-a-git-console-how-do-i-execute-a-batch-file-and-then-return-to-git-conso)
`cmd "/C clean.bat"`

Is there some option to just run the `clean.bat`?

Thank you very much

---

I solve that by updating all libraries... Maybe Cygwin? I am not sure, but update all your software and it works.

Comment: Maybe a shebang at the start of the file such as `;!cmd.exe /c`? Other than that, no, there probably isn't a way to do what you're asking.

Comment: You have to use cmd.exe , as windows isn't smart enough to know  which shell can execute a batch file

Comment: When I use old version of MSysGit, I can run directly `clean.bat`

Comment: Why not make a `bash` alias instead of using a batch file? Or make a `clean` alias that will run `cmd /c clean.bat`.

Answer (score 13):

Try this from MINGW command line

```
$ cmd <test.bat
```

Comment: Note there should be space between the "<" and "test.bat" if you want it to run in the same console window. Having no space will open a new window.

Comment: Note that mingw requires the .bat file to have the line break in the end, or else the last line will be ignored

Answer (score 0):

Try this from MINGW command line

```
$ eval "./test.bat"

D:\workspace>echo hello world
hello world
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from redirection `cmd < clean.bat` you might also like:

```bash
# Basic case - pipeline
echo clean.bat | cmd

# Feeding two commands - pipeline
echo -e "cd (cygpath -w ~/some_folder)\nclean.bat" | cmd # note the -e switch and \n char...

# For multiline cases the "here document" is the most readable form
cmd << MYEND
:: Here we go
cd `cygpath -w ~/my-folder`
setenv.bat
:: some_other_commands (?)
clean.bat
MYEND
```