# using batch file to run git commands

Tags: git, batch-file, github, command

I have been trying to run a batch file that will fetch all branches from a predefined repo and checkout one of the branches.

```
git fetch --all
git checkout myBranch
pause
```

The response I get from the command line is that the commands run successfully but the folder I ran the file in, shows no evidence of having checkout any branch.

I have also tried checking out to the path of the folder and running the commands, still to no avail.

However, when I write the commands into the cmd it works correctly.

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: Is `myrepo` a branch name or a repository?

Comment: Take the [tour], read [Ask] and [MCVE]. It would help if you could cut & paste the observed output into your original post. Click on [Edit].

Comment: What do you mean by "_checkout one of the repos_"? Do you want to **clone** a _repo_ OR do you want to **checkout** a _branch_?

Comment: sorry misspoke myrepo mean the branch i was checking out and i did use the git fetch --all the single - was a typo

Comment: Please edit your post to fix this typo: "_i did use the git fetch --all the single - was a typo_". Then, also post the console output when you run the batch file. Chances are, you're checking out a non-existent branch.

Answer (score 2):

`git fetch --all` (double -) fetches from all remotes, not all branches. `fetch` always fetches all branches. (For `git push` you Need the parameter `--all` to push all branches.)

`git checkout myrepo` tries to checkout a branch called `myrepo`. Probably no branch of this name exists, so an error should be shown.

Answer (score -2):

what do you mean by 'shows no evidence of having checkout any repo' ?

When you run your batch, don't you see a message like Switched to branche.. or already on .. ?

Comment: sorry my repo was a typo i meant a branch that i was trying to checkout

Answer (score -2):

A [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11865085/out-of-a-git-console-how-do-i-execute-a-batch-file-and-then-return-to-git-conso/36659733#36659733) indicates the commands `cmd "/C clean.bat"` or `./clear.bat` will give you your desired result.